# Cron job does not work

Tags: ruby, bash, cron

I am trying to write a scraper in ruby. It looks like this: [Router](http://pastebin.com/fBxutEh8) + [Worker](http://pastebin.com/RdF4zW4f) and a main script that loads router and call method `callWorkers`.

I put my files in `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR.openshift/cron/minutely/` and I have a simple bash script that says: `nohup ruby $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR.openshift/cron/minutely/main.rb &`.

My problem is: if I SSH in my app on openshift, go to `app-root/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely` and run exactly the same command from my bash script (`nohup ruby $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR.openshift/cron/minutely/main.rb &`) my scripts works perfectly, but when cron tries to start the script - it doesn't work. I have no idea how to manage this situation :(

Comment: what is the error ? what is the PATH ?

Comment: @michael501 The log look like this: [Log entry](http://pastebin.com/3vTTv6bA). I think the problem is here: '/var/lib/openshift/549c27945973ca1c6700010b/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/cron/minutely/main.rb: line 1: load: command not found'

Comment: this has nothing with cron , try to run it from command line and fix errors.

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact `cron` line and the exact contents of the `bash` script? From the logs, it looks like your ruby script is being interpreted as a `bash` or other shell script.

Comment: I solved the problem. I dropped the bash script and I made my ruby script executable. I used this shebang: '#!/usr/bin/env ruby' and now it works like a charm! I noticed that on openshift cron job tries to execute all content of the 'minutely, hourly, daily, monthly' directoryes. Thanks so much for your interest!

Comment: @kitz recommend you add your comment as an answer so you can mark this question off

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I dropped the bash script and I made my ruby script executable. 
I used this shebang: `'#!/usr/bin/env ruby'` and now it works like a charm! I noticed that on openshift cron job tries to execute all content of the 'minutely, hourly, daily, monthly' directoryes. 
Thanks so much for your interest!